# Query in symfony not working

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a query in the model of my table:
`$q = $this->createQuery('a')
              ->where('a.img1 = null')
              ->orderBy('a.created_at DESC')
              ->limit(4);`
The thing is that it returns nothing, but in DB there is an entry with no image (img1 field is null). What am I doing wrong? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = $this->createQuery('a')
          ->where('a.img1 IS NULL') // It needs to be IS NULL instead of = null
          ->orderBy('a.created_at DESC') 
          ->limit(4);
```

Don't forget `->execute()`!

Comment: Thank you so much... it's working fine now! I forget the `$q->execute();` on the question but I had it in the code already:)

Comment: Yep, I forget it often, too! :)